# Is the path of enlightenment consists 7 levels?

Tags: personal-practice, enlightenment, comparative-religion, meditation-hindrances

In this question [The Seven Factors of Enlightenment](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/180/the-seven-factors-of-enlightenment) shown, Tranquility, Concentration, Equanimity, Investigation of dhammas, Effort and Rapture as specific phases in the path of enlightenment (also in a linear progression), and how to apply them. Also [here](http://www.meditationexpert.com/ebok/howtomeditate.pdf).

The seven levels of consciousness which make up the [path of spiritual development](http://tmhome.com/books-videos/7-states-of-consciousness-video-interview/), shown in TM as:

1. the state of waking consciousness;
2. deep sleep;
3. dreaming;
4. transcendental consciousness;
5. cosmic consciousness;
6. god consciousness;
   unity consciousness.

Are these steps equally valued in the Buddhist path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to point out the following:

1. [TM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_Meditation) and Buddhist path are not the same. TM aim at `method for relaxation, stress reduction, and self-development` while Buddhism aims at eliminating the [Defilement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleshas_(Buddhism)) and one's attachment to the 5 aggregates hence reduce the process of [fabrication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sa%E1%B9%85kh%C4%81ra) thus experiencing [Nirvana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirvana_(Buddhism)).
2. The 7 factors of enlightenment are not linear. An interesting article which shows their interaction is in [Bojjhangas– Another View](http://journal.samatha.org/issues/2014/bojjhangas%E2%80%93-another-view). Also look at the table [balancing the factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Factors_of_Enlightenment#Meditation) in the Wikipedia entry on [Seven Factors of Enlightenment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Factors_of_Enlightenment) which gives when to emphasize each of the factors.

Comment: I like to know When and How the paths are deffer. say is there a level like 'deep sleep' in Buddhist path. If so how it is represent or what is call it. If the levels are deffer then how It is. Thanks for the links ( Bojjhangas Another View).

Comment: There is. It is Sloth-torpor (thīna-middha) which is one of the [hindrances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_hindrances). This is not considered wholesome.